# Что за порт 8888 на роутере и для чего он нужен?

Tags: роутер, порты

[image: http://i.imgur.com/HepdmU4.png]

Что за порт 8888 на роутере и для чего он нужен?

Answer (score 1):

Да может быть все что угодно

```
8888/TCP,UDP    NewsEDGE server Официально8888/TCP    Sun Answerbook dwhttpd server (deprecated)[59]  Неофициально8888/TCP    GNUmp3d HTTP music streaming and Web interface  Неофициально8888/TCP    LoLo Catcher HTTP Web interface (www.optiform.com)
```

Скорее всего что там какой нить web-server для чего то. Попробуйте браузером туда зайти. И скорее всего что этот порт через wan  не торчит.

Comment: повторил твой ответ )) прости, что невнимательно прочитал.

Comment: это я и сам посмотрел. так же я понимаю что это может быть все что угодно. не получается зайти по этому порту. я думал что это что это какой то сервис специфичный для d-linka.

Comment: а что за модель роутера, прошивка? понятно, что теоретически может быть всё, что угодно, но я склоняюсь к тому, что это что-то вполне себе стандартное, описанное в даташите к модели или прошивке.

Comment: D-Link DSL-2640U. Прошивка - 1.0.20.

Answer (score 1):

Обычно это порт для управления роутером по протоколу HTTP.

Если браузером зайти на http://192.168.1.1:8888/ ?

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос давний, но когда-то он меня тоже сильно заинтересовал. В данный момент я занимаюсь данным вопросом. Для начала этот порт открыт на любом устройстве `D-LINK` там ещё кстати `9999` открыт если что. Если заходить через `telnet` то программа отвечающая за данный порт вернёт `!<=>` и `FAIL`  в ответ. Прошивка скачана с рускоязычного сайта `d-link.ru` я полагаю, так как в прошивке с англоязычного сайта данной программы нет. Бинарник называется 'resident', в комплекте с ним так же идёт бинарник с кричщим названием `resident_cli`, что предполагает наличие пользовательского интерфейса. Так оно и есть, если например вы залогинетесь через `telnet`, как обычно к `23` порту и просто наберёте `resident_cli`, то вам будет предложено ввести логи и пароль (они совпадают с вашими, те что набираете при входе через браузер). При правильном вводе пароля откроется что то вроде `super root` доступа в консоле с некоторыми функциями, которые никак не назовёшь стандартными. Повторюсь, вопрос исследован не до конца. Но лично моё мнение, это бэкдор с завода, причём ставится он только на отечественные прошивки.

Answer (score 0):

Зайди на него телнетом

`telnet 192.168.1.1 8888`

если откликнется - поймешь по отклику кто это. Если нет - забей.

Comment: не спортивно. я хочу решить вопрос коллективным разумом)) отклика нет.

Comment: @Денис Проскурин , отклика нет, потому-что ваш вопрос похож на >>ребята, какой тип жильца живет в 42й квартире в моем доме? т.е. правильный ответ - стандарта на это нет, пойди проверь.

Comment: )) вопрос был для тех, кто, возможно, знает специфику d-linka, потому что на любой порт можно повесить любой сервис. вопрос поставлен корректно, я даже скриншот приложил.